# chemnum numbering only working in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, vscode, chemnum

I am new to LaTeX. I want to use the VSCode extension to do my LaTeX project. I need the chemnum package to work. I ran exactly the same code in overleaf and locally. The Labels TMP1 and TMP2 are only replaced when run in overleaf. This is how the local output looks and is also how my .eps file looks.

[image: How my local pdf file looks / also exactly how my eps file looks.]

The code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}
    \replacecmpd{first:compound}  %% automatically replace TMP1
    \replacecmpd{second:compound}  %% automatically replace TMP2
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/label_test.eps}
    \caption{This is something!}
    \label{first:chem:scheme}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

The log files can be found here: https://ufile.io/f/0ftc5
.eps file can be found here: https://ufile.io/cy8zurmk

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your document works fine using pdfLaTeX and with `example-image`.

Comment: Thanks!, 
I use pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023), kpathsea version 6.3.5.
Any guess why my local latex does not replace the TMP1/2 locally? Any similar occurrences? I am not even sure what I am looking for.

Comment: I use few days ago installed and updated MiKTeX. Sorry, I don't know what is going wrong at your LaTeX installation.

Comment: You can't compile with pdflatex, you need latex + dvips + ps2pdf

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. It compiles just fine. The only issue is that it does not replace TMP1 with the correct number in the file but instead keeps the temp label in the graphic. It should automatically replace it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes this is the correct answer although it took me a while to understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was to define a latex recipe in vscode that includes all relevant steps (see comment chain on original post).

1. Went into settings.json
2. added these two blocks to it:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk-dvips-ps2pdf",
            "tools": ["latexmk-dvips-ps2pdf-command"]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk-dvips-ps2pdf-command",
            "command": "cmd.exe",
            "args": [
                "/c",
                "latexmk %DOCFILE% && dvips %DOCFILE%.dvi -o %DOCFILE%.ps && ps2pdf %DOCFILE%.ps %DOCFILE%.pdf"
                
            ],
            "env": {}
        }
    ],
```

3. Ctrl+Shift+P `>LaTeX Workshop: Build with recipe`

This compiled correctly replacing the TMP labels.